# Making a custom book for a command mod w\ Almighty Commands

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

This is the status quo:

I have finished making the very structure of the Command Module I'm making, and I'm trying to add in a command that gives me a book that has contents in it.

I succeeded in 10% of the command, which is coloring the first part of the book, only problem is, the next part of text after it is supposed to be colored black, which it isn't.[image: see the red part after 'The Lab'?]

I've tried this [post](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/redstone-discussion-and/351959-1-8-raw-json-text-examples-for-tellraw-title-books) from the Minecraft Forums, however I found it unhelpful, as I've tried on what it says about inheritance.

P.S. My Minecraft version is 1.8.9.

Comment: There is currently a bug that causes a difference in how inheritance works within books compared to other features using the text component (see [MC-62866](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-62866)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Identifying The Problem

I think the problem is that you need to update the "-----" at the end to black. The part I have highlighted below shows that those are going together. (The "The Lab" and the ending "-----" both have the same red and bold.)

[image: Picture 1]

### Solving The Problem

To solve this, you will want to insert this... (Between where the " and ] are; near the red.)
[image: Picture 2]

Example:

```
/give @p written_book 1 0 {resolved:0,generation:0,author:"Ry3ks3u",title:"The Lab",pages:["[\"------------------\",\"\n-----\",{\"text\":\"The Lab\",\"color\":\"dark_red\",\"bold\":true},{\"text\":\"-----\",\"color\":\"black\"}]"]}
```